# Xcode Assistant view Header and Source don't match up

Tags: xcode

Up until today I had been using assistant view with source on the left in the main and then the headers in the right in the assistant view. When I changed the source file, it used to show the correct header file in the assistant view, but now it is just acting like two seperate views.

What did I do to break it and how do I fix it?

edit. I closed it and opened it again and it fixed it. So the problem is solved but the question is still valid. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a popup at the top of the Assistant editor window:

- "Manual": Assistant editor is just a separate independent editor window,
- "Counterparts": The corresponding counterpart for the main view is shown automatically,
- and many more options ...